# Install VMware Tools in OS X El Capitan Guest

Tags: vmware

I installed El Capitan on VMware Pro 12.0 running on x64 Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 using this [torrented image](https://kat.cr/os-x-10-11-el-capitan-vmware-image-t11386865.html). While trying to install VMware tools, I get an error saying ***Could not find component on update server***.

Everything went smooth on Windows 10 host, so I suppose image is fine.

I would appreciate if someone could recommend a work-around like downloading required components and manually installing them.
[image: osx_vmware_error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, you should have contacted *VMWare Support*, who would have likely pointed you at [this knowledge base article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1032440), which details how to install the tools in a MacOS guest, and which also states that MacOS guests are only supported on *VMware Fusion*.